# Create an array of arrays using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My goal is to create an array that look something like this

```
var locations = [
    [
        "New Mermaid",
        36.9079,
        -76.199
    ],
    [
        "1950 Fish Dish",
        36.87224,
        -76.29518
    ]
];
```

**I've tried**

```
var data = $locations;
var locations = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  locations[i] =
  data[i]['name']+','+
  data[i]['lat']+','+
  data[i]['lng'];

}

console.log(locations);
```

---

**I've got**

```
["Apple  HQ,33.0241101,39.5865834", "Google MA,43.9315743,20.2366877"]
```

However that is not the exact format.

---

**I want**

```
var locations = [
    [
        "New Mermaid",
        36.9079,
        -76.199
    ],
    [
        "1950 Fish Dish",
        36.87224,
        -76.29518
    ]
];
```

How do I update my JS to get something like that ?

Comment: Why do you want an array that contains arrays that each contain 1 string?

Comment: That is not an object.  An object would be: `{company: 'Apple HQ', lat: '33.024', long: '39.586'}`.

Comment: Sorry, I might have upload the wrong format. I updated my post. Thanks for poiting that out.

Comment: Provide your expected output

Comment: You want an array of *arrays*.  Build the array first, then append it to your master array.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya : I just updated my post.

Comment: @cale_b: Technically, that is not true. An array is an object in Javascript. Run `typeof []` and see for yourself.

Comment: @Amberlamps - that's because technically *everything* in javascript is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To  build an "Array of arrays", this is one (of a few different methods):

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  locations[i] = [];
  locations[i][0] = data[i]['name'];
  locations[i][1] = data[i]['lat'];
  locations[i][2] = data[i]['lng'];
}
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  locations[i] = [data[i]['name'], data[i]['lat'], data[i]['lng']];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var locations = data.map(function(location){
  return [ location.name, location.lat, location.lng ];
}
```

Map will make an array with all the returned values from your function. Each return will be an array consisting of the 3 attributes you are looking for.

Comment: Very nice!  Great solution.

Comment: Rather this: `return [ location.name, location.lat, location.lng ];`